# Is there a count type of method that you can use on a Python set?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, count, set

For example (which did not work):

```
rock_group = ([])
if rock_group.count() <= 12:
    rock_group.add(a_rock)
```

I'm looking to count the number of items in a set and if it is less than 12, then add the object `a_rock` to the set.

I was hoping to write something quicker and more efficient than a for loop.

Comment: By the way, in `rock_group = ([])`... The parentheses! They do nothing!

Comment: You'd have to roll your own and it's still not guaranteed to be faster than O(N) for a default `Set`.

Comment: Yeah, forgot the "set". Thanks guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `len(rock_group)`. Also your `rock_group` is currently a list, not a set.

To create a set you can write: `rock_group = set()`. This means the code becomes:

```
rock_group = set()
if len(rock_group) <= 12:
    rock_group.add(a_rock)
```